# duplicity when adding new input with angular and autocomplete material

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material

I have a form, in which I have several input with autocomplete, based on an * ngFor, but when adding a new one, the input takes the value of the last input that was modified.
Here I have an example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q2zfmf?file=app/autocomplete-filter-example.html
Does anyone know how this problem could be solved?

Comment: It's because they're all bound to the same `FormControl`

Comment: How can I do it to have dynamic formcontrol?